# I have this conjecture. can you please give me a proof? I could not find proof.

Tags: combinatorics, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

$$ \left(\begin{array}{c}p\\ k\end{array}\right)\equiv\frac{p}{k}\bmod p $$
where p is composite number and k is one of its prime factor.

Comment: You use "$p$" to denote a composite and "$k$" to denote a prime?  That seems unnecessarily confusing.

Comment: Even though the notation is somewhat awkward, I don't think that much downvoting is justified. It's an interesting conjecture, and I'm not surprised OP didn't find a proof, immediately. Neither did you guys.

Answer (score 9):

We have $$\binom{n-1}{p-1} = \frac{(n-1) \dotsb (n-p+1)}{(p-1)!}$$

Modulo $p$ the numerator is also $(p-1)!$, thus the quotient is $1$ modulo $p$, i.e. $\binom{n-1}{p-1}=1+ap$ for some $a \in \mathbb Z$.

This yields $$\binom{n}{p}=\frac{n}{p}\binom{n-1}{p-1}=\frac{n}{p}(1+ap)=\frac{n}{p}+an = \frac{n}{p} \mod n.$$